# Java almostIncreasingSequence

Tags: java

Okay so i just started out on CodeFight, I got this question:

[image]
After a couple of hours of trying to figure a way by myself to solve it i got it fully functional but apperently its not within the time limit, and I do not know how to fix it even more to solve it.

```
boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    List<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++){
        A.add(sequence[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
        ArrayList<Integer> AC = new ArrayList<Integer>(A);
        AC.remove(i);
        boolean ps = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < AC.size()-1; x++){
            if (AC.get(x) >= AC.get(x+1)){
                ps = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ps){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This what I'm getting

[image]

I know there are questions just like this out there but i haven't found a solution. I hope someone can help. I have been stuck for hours on this.

Comment: Why are you re-storing the sequence?

Comment: Why are you calling AC.remove(i) instead of AC.remove( A.get(i) ).

Comment: @Dana I didn't know how i would manage Manage the sequence if it wasnt in an arrayList form.

Comment: AC is a copy of the original sequence and wanted to remove stuff from the copy instead directly from the given sequence. so I dont mess it up.

Comment: @tsolakp Those aren't equivalent statements.

Comment: There is a reason CodeFights have performance test. Usually they indicate that your algorithm   does not perform and needs rethinking instead of trying to fine tune it. I personally think that you need to change your algorithm not to do nested loops and list copying.

Comment: I feel like this question would be better suited for CodeReview

Comment: I will of course try my best, and update if I find a solution

Comment: You really don't need nested loops for this.  You can just iterate through the array once, and if you find a step where the sequence doesn't increase, check whether removing one of the two elements either side of that step makes the sequence increase.

Comment: @Radiodef, agree, initially I thought the remove was called to remove by element and not by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code for your problem should have looked like this

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println( "Output: " + almostIncreasingSequence( new int[]{1,3,2,1} ) );
    System.out.println("\r\n");
    System.out.println( "Output: " + almostIncreasingSequence( new int[]{1,3,2} ) ) ;
    System.out.println("\r\n");
    System.out.println( "Output: " + almostIncreasingSequence( new int[]{1,3,5,12,15,2} ) );
}

public static boolean almostIncreasingSequence( int[] array )
{
    boolean hasIncreasingSequenceNature = false;
    for( int x = 0; x < array.length; x++ )
    {
        boolean almostIncreasingWithRemovedElement = assumeRemovedElement(x , array);
        System.out.println( "Removing " + array[x] + " would produce INCREASING SEQUENCE?: " + almostIncreasingWithRemovedElement);
        if( almostIncreasingWithRemovedElement )
        {
            hasIncreasingSequenceNature = true;
        }               
    }
    return hasIncreasingSequenceNature;
}

public static boolean assumeRemovedElement( int assumeRemovedIndex , int[] data )
{
    boolean isIncreasing = false;
    for( int x = 0; x < data.length - 1; x++ )
    {
        if( x == ( assumeRemovedIndex - 1 ) )
        {
            if( (x < data.length - 2 ) )
            {
                if( data[x] < data[x + 2] )
                {
                    isIncreasing = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isIncreasing = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if( x != assumeRemovedIndex )
        {
            if( data[x] < data[x + 1] )
            {
                isIncreasing = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isIncreasing = false;
                break;
            }               
        }
    }
    return isIncreasing;
}
```

I guess the part where you are confusing is the **removing an element from an array**, but this does not require that you actually make attempts to remove things from the array, rather find an iterative approach, that helps you skip **the assumed removed element** and let the code keep track of the increasing sequence within the array, during the iteration

Explaining the code, **boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[])** really does nothing but makes a brute-force kind of attempt, on every element in the list, to see how would **assumeRemovedElement(int byIndex , int[] yourSequence)** return when the incrementing-sequence checking algo is applied by skipping the array element with **byIndex** variable. Once we find that **assumeRemovedElement(int , int[])** returns true, **almostIncreasingSequence(int[])** flags it's **hasIncreasingSequenceNature** as true or false, so that the final output could be analyzed, because remember, you have to check the sequence by **assuming the removal of each and every element in the array**, hence the term brute force

**assumeRemovedElement( int assumeRemovedIndex , int[] data)** applies the algo where the increasing sequence within array is checked by making sure that we don't encounter any kind of situation involving the **comparison with the assumed removed element in the array** and those safety measures are taken when **if( x == ( assumeRemovedIndex - 1 ) )** and **else if( x != assumeRemovedIndex )** execute within the loop where we struggle to maintain our increasing sequence checking code with basic if/else constructs, Hope that clarifies a lot, but certainly open to further discussions

Comment: Thank you, It helped a lot.

Comment: No problem, but initially your question had a +1 rating :) I don't know how it got rated down to -1 :( . But as a future recommendation, remember to textualize your problem description and avoid using pngs or gifs for problem description, I won't be able to help you with the question voting now that I have an answer to it :D , so no worries just take care of making your problem description more elaborate and text-based, in the future ofcourse :) , @Fredrik Hansen also proposed a nice solution, it's worth trying out too

Answer (score 1):

You might need to consider another approach to the problem. This problem can be solved in linear time by evaluating each entry once. An entry can either be part of an increasing sequence, part of an almost increasing sequence or neither.

A sequence will be almost increasing if it contains less than two of these almost increasing entries, so we can simply check for that at the end.

```
public enum EntryState {
    INCREASING(0), ALMOST_INCREASING(1), DECREASING(2);

    private final int state;
    private EntryState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public int getValue() { return state; }
}

public boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    int l = sequence.length;
    EntryState[] sequenceState = new EntryState[l];
    for(int i = 0; i < l - 1; i++) {
        if(sequence[i] <= sequence[i + 1])
            sequenceState[i] = EntryState.INCREASING;
        else if((i + 2 >= l) || (i + 2 < l && sequence[i] <= sequence[i + 2]))
            sequenceState[i] = EntryState.ALMOST_INCREASING;
        else
            sequenceState[i] = EntryState.DECREASING;
    }
    sequenceState[l - 1] = EntryState.INCREASING;

    int sum = 0;
    for(EntryState e : sequenceState)
        sum += e.getValue();

    int sumWithoutStart = sum - sequenceState[0].getValue();
    int sumWithoutEnd = sum - sequenceState[l - 1].getValue();
    return sumWithoutStart == 0 || sumWithoutEnd == 0 || sum < 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version basically just constructs the sequence accounting for various cases and then check the size of the seq we created. If the size of increasingSeq is only 1 less than the size of the array we are passed in then we know there is only one error. If it is off by any more than 1 then we know there are multiple errors in the seq and must return false. This took me a while to think about its kinda an easy/ weirdly hard problem idk. This code could be cleaner too but ima move on from it.

```
boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> increasingSeq = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(sequence.length > 1)
    {   
        int prev, cur;
    
        for(int i = 1; i < sequence.length; i++)
        {
            prev = sequence[i - 1];
            cur = sequence[i];
        
            if(prev < cur)
            {
                if(increasingSeq.size() == 0 || increasingSeq.get(increasingSeq.size() - 1) < cur)
                {
                    increasingSeq.add(cur);
                }
            }
            else if(prev > cur)
            {
                if(increasingSeq.size() > 1 && increasingSeq.get(increasingSeq.size() - 2) < cur)
                {
                    increasingSeq.remove((increasingSeq.size() - 1));
                    increasingSeq.add(cur);
                }
           
            }   
        }
    }

    if((increasingSeq.size() + 1) == (sequence.length - 1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```